# maxLength property is not working on EditText

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext

I have the following `EditText` where I have set maximum character limit to 10, but somehow it is not working. It accepts more than 10 characters.

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:hint="Enter Full Name *"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:padding="5dip" />
```

Please helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: fixed title and added edittext tag

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any `InputFilter` set to the `EditText` by code.

You should comment this line of code.

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this. This is the simple hack around this problem if you are setting it from xml.

Internally if your suggestion is switched on then as per dictionary its not able to judge the word character length. So If it has been switched off then maxlength will work and Android will understand it as own written word,where no dictionary should be applicable.

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
 android:maxLength="10"
```